# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in react.js

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am trying to use the **useHistory** hook in **react.js** ,  i dont't understand why i am getting error **can not react property push of undefined** .

code:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
  const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState("");
  const [signinLoader, setsinginLoader] = useState(false);
  const [opterror, setoptError] = useState("");

const history = useHistory()
  useEffect(() => {
    const userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
    if (userInfo) {
      history.push("/users");
    }
  }, [history]);
```

**here is complete code of my app.js file check the useState hook where i am trying to use useHistory hook but its not working , getting error cannot read push of undefined**

```
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Signup from "./components/Signup";
import Signin from "./components/login";
import Users from "./components/users";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
function App() {
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
  const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState("");
  const [signinLoader, setsinginLoader] = useState(false);
  const [opterror, setoptError] = useState("");

const history = useHistory()
  useEffect(() => {
    const userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
    if (userInfo) {
      history.push("/");
    }
  }, [history]);

  const formDataSender = async (FormData) => {
    setLoader(true);
    try {
      if (FormData) {
        let res = await axios.post("/api/users", FormData, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        });

        if (res) {
          setLoader(false);
          console.log(res);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setErrMsg("");
          }, 1000);

          return setErrMsg(res.data.message);
        }
        return setErrMsg(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setErrMsg(true);
    }
  };

  const timer = (message) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setoptError(message);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const loginSender = async (formData) => {
    if (formData) {
      setsinginLoader(true);
      try {
        let res = await axios.post("/api/users/login", formData);
        console.log(res);
        if (res.data.message) {
          localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(res.data));
          setsinginLoader(false);
          setoptError("login successful !");
          timer("");
          return console.log(res);
        }

        setsinginLoader(false);
        setoptError(res.data.showmessage);
        timer("");
      } catch (error) {
        timer("");
        setoptError("login failed !!");
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <div className="App">
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <Signin
              passtologinhandler={loginSender}
              loader={signinLoader}
              additionalInfo={opterror}
            />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/signup">
            <Signup
              passedToSignUpHandler={formDataSender}
              loading={loader}
              err={errMsg}
            />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
        </div>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package.json[image: package.json]

Comment: Have you wrap your application with `BrouserRouter` ?

Comment: @MajidM. yes i have added additional code check it out

Comment: `useHistory` should be used in a children Component of Router. You're using it at root, so history is not defined

Comment: @dbuchet i shoud pass histroy as props then??

Comment: Nope, you should only use `useHistory` within a children. So maybe just rewrite your component to have `<Router> <App /></Router>` and you'll be able to use `useHistory` in `App`

Comment: @dbuchet thanks it worked , can u please explain what was the problem and how  what was the mainr reason behind solution a bit clearly , thanks

Comment: @dbuchet now i am facing another problem even though i get data and  the if condition is true the history.psuh("/users") does not redirect but as i refresh the page again it redirects ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the `loginSender`,`signinLoader`,`opterror` as props in `Signin` component. Move all the functionality into `Signin` component. So in the `Signin` component, you should have something like this:

```
export const Signin =(props)=>{
  const [signinLoader, setsinginLoader] = useState(false);
  const [opterror, setoptError] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    const userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
    if (userInfo) {
      history.push("/");
    }
  }, []);


  const loginSender = async (formData) => {
    if (formData) {
      setsinginLoader(true);
      try {
        let res = await axios.post("/api/users/login", formData);
        console.log(res);
        if (res.data.message) {
          localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(res.data));
          setsinginLoader(false);
          setoptError("login successful !");
          timer("");
          return console.log(res);
        }

        setsinginLoader(false);
        setoptError(res.data.showmessage);
        timer("");
      } catch (error) {
        timer("");
        setoptError("login failed !!");
      }
    }
  };
....

}
```

**App:**

```
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <div className="App">
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <Signin/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/signup">
            <Signup/>
          </Route>   
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
        </div>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

You should do the same thing for `Signup`.

Comment: M , AoA bro thanks   , still its not working , i have done the same previously  this time  i dont know why its not working its a simple thing .

Comment: @nodeDev Check my answer again.

Comment: thanks alot brother , really appreciate  your help ,  i  am going to implement your changes right now , thanks again :)